# How can I run dregcmd from VB silent and output results to a file

Tags: cmd.exe, azure, vbscript, azure-activedirectory

There's one result from dsregcmd that is crucial to what I need that other methods don't do related to Azure,dsregcmd /status.

It won't succeed if shelled out to cmd nor run from anything I have found other than from manaully in the cmd prompt.

What I must determine is ADJoined and/or EnterpriseJoined

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Device State                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

             AzureAdJoined : NO  <--- THIS
          EnterpriseJoined : NO  <--- THIS
```

What else can I try?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the info via other methods? Or via parsing the output of `dsregcmd /status`?

Comment: What I want to be able to do is launch the command `dsregcmd /status >C:\some-path\output.txt` invisibly.  I can handle reading the resulting output text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch the command "invisibly", you can try do the following:

1. Open a text editor and enter the code below:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "dsregcmd /status >C:\Somepath\output.txt", 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

2. Save the file with a `vbs` extension for example `test.vbs`.
3. Double-click the file to execute the command. Then open the output file to read the content.

The second line of the code executes the command `dsregcmd /status >C:\Users\Reddy\output.txt` and hides the window (`0`).

See [WSH » wshshell » Run](https://devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-run.html)

Comment: Doesn't work but this does:


`Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "cmd /c dsregcmd /status >C:\SomePath\output.txt", 0
Set WshShell = Nothing`

Comment: Does work on my side without `cmd`.

Comment: Works from .bat and .vbs but if you call dsregcmd from a compiled .exe or even call a launch of a .bat or .vbs file to run it, even logged in as Admin, or elevating the .exe, it fails.  Basically, if you need to check for this at another computer, no you can't.

And that's the key, we need to ensure trad on-prem or Azure AD joined.  Worse still, a PC can still show "WORKGROUP" *and* be Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in the comment that it fails to run from a compiled executable. It might be because you try to run it from a 32 bit process. `dsregcmd` is only available as a 64 bit process. You can use `sysnative` virtual folder to launch a 64 bit command from a 32 bit executable.